# Best way to present 5 choices and still fit in the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a field that has 5 different formatting options. In the app's settings I was originally using a `UISegmentedControl` inside a grouped style `UITableViewCell`. Back when it only had 3 options. But now that there are 5 even with abbreviated text the text won't fit on iPhone sized screen in portrait. They fit fine in landscape, but since the rest of the app works best in portrait it seems really bad practice to force only the settings to be landscape. Also the only way I see to force landscape on only the settings table view is to use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];` which seems to be a undocumented/private API so I shouldn't use it. I have various other settings cells with `UISegmentedControls` in them, and they work fine. If I change the `UISegmentedControl's` style to `UISegmentedControlStyleBar` it fits properly. I'm just not sure that that is a good fit. What way do you think I should go with this? I'm not 100% sure on the % or Over 12 text but I need something similar. Is there some way to adjust the font size with the standard `UISegmentedControl`?

[image] [image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I usually handle this is to navigate to another view when the table cell is selected. Apple's iOS "Settings" app is a prime example of this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a picker view or a separate table view instead of a segmented control.

Comment: I had completely forgotten the picker view. If I did that it should be in a nested view anyway right?

Comment: I managed to implement a picker view that slides up like the keyboard on tapping a cell (while staying in the same VC), but if you want to go the easier route you can push another VC instead.

Comment: Picker views are OK, but sometimes they just clash with your application's theme.